# Angular Material2 use different theme (colors) for different builds/environments

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I got an Angular6 app that uses the CLI and material2 with a custom theme. Now for another customer I want to use that same app, but with different colors. How can I do this? I don't want to maintain a second code base so it has to be something with the build and/or environment I think so?

My theme which is imported in `styles.scss`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here 
so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design 
palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a 
default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue, 500);
$app-accent: mat-palette($mat-blue, 900);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each 
component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using angular 6, you can use the `fileReplacements` configuration section in `angular.json`.
Using this, you can have a file customer1.theme.scss replacing the file theme.scss only when building for a certain environment.

Here is an exemple :

```
{
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/customer/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/customer/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "projects/customer/src/themes/theme.scss",
                  "with": "projects/customer/src/themes/theme.prod.scss"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that looks promising! Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: I've put an example in the anwser

Comment: Wow amazing exactly what I need. However a bug in 6.0.* prevents html and scss files from being replaced. Seems to be fixed in 6.1.*

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for `scss` files. Only `.ts` files are supported and `html` will be very soon.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take would be to use basic CSS classes for this. In your theme file, define different themes:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

// Define a default theme
$light-default-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$light-default-accent:  mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
$light-default-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$light-default-theme:   mat-light-theme($light-default-primary, $light-default-accent, $light-default-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($light-default-theme);

.light-blue-theme {

  $light-blue-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
  $light-blue-accent:  mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
  $light-blue-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
  $light-blue-theme:   mat-light-theme($light-blue-primary, $light-blue-accent, $light-blue-warn);

  @include angular-material-theme($light-blue-theme);
}

.dark-theme {

  $dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-cyan);
  $dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
  $dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
  $dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

and in your `evnironments.ts` file, define the customer: (you would need separate environments for each customer I guess)

```
export const client = {
 clientName: 'xxx'
}
```

In your component you can set the current customer:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  public clientName: string = this.env.client.clientName; // imported from environments.ts
...
```

Then in your template you can add the relevant class to your main container:

```
<div [class.light-blue-theme]="clientName === 'xxx'" [class.dark-theme]="clientName === 'yyy'">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, got a question. I'm using the following line somewhere: `background-color: mat-color($app-primary)`. This obviously won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think that should still work since it will use the primary color of the currently active theme.

Comment: A compile error won't recognize the variable `$app-primary`

Comment: You could try add a default theme (see edit). Otherwise you may need to look at a different approach.

Comment: A possible solution is this: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components However this requiered you to create a mixin file/function in every component.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple achive this by using environemt variable.

```
// environment.ts (under the environments folder)
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  headerColor: 'green'
};

// environment.test.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  headerColor: 'blue'
};

// environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  headerColor: 'yellow'
};

// in the header component
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

headerColor: string = environment.headerColor;
```

Use this variable headerColor in html file to dynamic add color